# Grub not showing Windows 10 entry

Tags: windows-10, multi-boot, uefi, debian-stretch

After installing Windows 10 I installed Debian 9 in a different partition. I wanted to have dual boot. However something went wrong and currently only Debian is displayed as unique OS in the selectable start list.
These are the partitions:

- sda1: EFI system
- sda2 and sda3: Windows 10
- sda3: Debian

How can I make the two OSs to be shown in the list?

Things I tried:

1. Installing GRUB in the MRB instead of in the sda1 as UEFI
2. Use the tool Grub repair

After 2 (at some point) two entries of Windows were displayed in the GRUB. However I could only see the wallpaper of Debian but no trace of the login box where to insert my credentials.

**Update**
Currently I broke the grub. At start up there is a black script with the message:

> error: file '/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod' not found. grub rescue>

I followed the following [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/266429/error-file-grub-i386-pc-normal-mod-not-found)

However normal.mod is not inside the folder grub:

```
grub rescue> ls (hd0,msdos6)/boot/grub/
```

> unicode.pf2 x86_64-efi/ locale/ fonts/ grubenv grub.cfg

Answer (score 0):

Grub reads it's boot configuration from `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`, which is generated by `grub-mkconfig`.
grub-mkconfig reads `/etc/defaults/grub` for configuration variables, executes the files in `/etc/grub.d` and writes the output to the boot configuration.

One of the files in /etc/grub.d should be named `30_os-prober`. That file, if it exists, should call `os-prober` (if it's not disabled in /etc/defaults/grub).

So, to find out, where stuff goes wrong, check if os-prober works and outputs something like `/dev/sda1:Windows 10:Windows:chain` (that's my EFI partition).

If it does, check if os-prober is disabled in /etc/defaults/grub and that /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober exists.

You could also manually add the entry in `/etc/grub.d/40_custom`. [The Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB#Custom_grub.cfg) has good information on how to do that.

Comment: After messing around I broke the grub. Currently my display is black showing `error: file '/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod' not found.
grub rescue>`

Answer (score 0):

First boot into debian and mount windows 10 partition. Then in terminal run `sudo os-prober && sudo update-grub`. Check if problem solves.